# what all python packages/libraries are in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

a.) for example I want to know numpy, [scipy](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/), [scikits](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/index.html) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) are there in google app engine
b.) is there a way to install them in there(insane question)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

App Engine bundles most of the standard library, with a few exceptions (`marshal` isn't available, `cPickle` is an alias for `pickle`, and modules dealing with, e.g., sockets, won't work), plus `webob`, `simplejson`, `django`, and `PyYAML`. You can see a listing [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python).

You can include any pure python libraries you want with your application. C extensions are not supported, which rules out numpy, scipy, and anything that depends on them (like the other 2 modules you mention.)

The Python 2.7 runtime, soon to go to trusted testers, will include numpy (along with PIL and lxml), but at the moment there's been no indication that arbitrary C extensions will be allowed any time soon (although there is some hope that they might eventually be allowed via NaCL.)

Answer (score 2):

PIL, NumPy, and lxml library [will be supported by Google App Engine in the future](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/4bde29d8e6dc0842)

Answer (score 1):

Since 13/14 Dec 2012, Google app engine supports numpy and matplotlib.

There's a catch that developer server doesn't support matplotlib out of the box, but that was relatively easy to hack around: http://gae-matplotlib-demo.appspot.com/

Pure-python modules you can include yourself, but I think scipy is not one of them, so you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 2.7,  **django, endpoints, jinja2, lxml, markupsafe, matplotlib, MySQLdb, numpy, PIL, protorpc, PyAMF, pycrypto, setuptools, ssl, webapp2, webob** are supported

Checkout this document for full list [Third-party Libraries in Python 2.7](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)